# Finding the value of $x^{x^2}+x^{x^6}$ given that $x^{x^4}=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, exponentiation

If $x^{x^4}=4$;
Then what is the value of $x^{x^2}+x^{x^6}$ ;  I just want a hint like from where should I start. (other than using a trial and error to find that $x=\sqrt{2}$ satisfies this and now just put it in the required equation!!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only ask for a hint, so here is one:

In $x^{x^4}=4$, raise both sides to the power $4$. This will give you
$$
(x^4)^{x^4}=4^4.
$$
It is clear that $x^4=4$ is one possibility, but maybe you can conclude that it is the only one, by studying the function
$$
c\mapsto c^c?
$$

**Edit**
Let us answer the following: What positive values of $c$ give $c^c=4^4$?

Let $f(c)=c^c$. Then
$$
f'(c)=c^c(1+\ln c),
$$
so, $f$ is monotonically decreasing for $0<c<1/e$ and monotonically increasing for $c>1/e$. Since $\lim_{c\to 0^+}f(c)=1$ and $f(1)=1$, we conclude that the equation $c^c=4^4$ *is only attained for one $c$*, namely the "obvious" $c=4$.

If we go back to your problem, this means that (here $c=x^4$)
$$
(x^4)^{x^4}=4^4\quad\implies\quad x^4=4.
$$
Ask for more information, if needed.

Comment: Well,honestly I think you got the idea of raising the equation to the power of 4 by looking at the solution I mentioned in the question by hit and trial but still I would not have been able to this also!!

Comment: And as for the part that " it is the only possibility..." Sorry but I don't understand symbols much can you please put the part c->c^2 in words so that I can at least understand what you are asking me to do!!

Comment: For your first comment: I did not get that idea from what you wrote in your question, but by grabbing a pen and paper and doing some manipulations. If you look at the first version of my answer, you will see that first, my method was less direct.

Comment: For the second comment: If we let $c=x^4$, then the question becomes, for what values of $c$ is $c^c=4^4$? The answer to this question can be found via a study of the function $c\mapsto c^c$ (typically using differentiation and studying the range of it, to see that it equals $4^4$ for one $c$ only.

Comment: Sorry @mickep I used I all the common little bit resources I had but I still couldn't state how this x=√2 is the only solution possible here,I even asked my teacher and all he said was use logarithm in the original equation and manipulate it further but I couldn't do this either can you help me,in any one of these solutions I got to know about.

Comment: Yeah,I know by doing this you will almost solve the question where all I asked for was a hint!!

Comment: I added some details in the answer.

Comment: Thnx,but I don't know such high level mathematics do you know of any other relatively easy solution which someone like me can understand otherwise ignore this !!
Maybe I will read this answer after a year when I am formally introduced to functions!! But thnx for the effort